# How do I extract data from a struct array?

Tags: c++

I've successfully stepped through my code and it is filling the array, but when I try to extract the data it tells me "Error. Expression must have class type"

```
void Inventory::fillInventory(char* buff, int len)
{
using namespace std;
int i = 0;
int upcNum = 0;
string itDesc = "";
string itPrice = "";
bool itTax = false;
do
{
    do
    {
        // assign upcNum
        if (buff[i] >= 48 && buff[i] <= 57)
        {
            string str = "";
            while (buff[i] != 32)
            {
                str += buff[i];
                i++;
            }
            upcNum = stoi(str, nullptr, 10);
        }
        // assign itDesc
        else if (buff[i] >= 97 && buff[i] <= 122)
        {
            string str = "";
            while (buff[i] != 32)
            {
                str += buff[i];
                i++;
            }
            itDesc = str;
        }
        // assign itPrice
        else if (buff[i] == 36)
        {
            string str = "";
            while (buff[i] != 32)
            {
                str += buff[i];
                i++;
            }
            itPrice = str;
        }
        // assign itTax
        else if (buff[i] == 78 || buff[i] == 84)
        {
            switch (buff[i])
            {
            case 78:
                itTax = false;
                break;
            case 84:
                itTax = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    } while (buff[i] != 10 && i < len);


    // fill struct
    newItem = new Item;
    newItem->upc = upcNum;
    newItem->desc = itDesc;
    newItem->cost = itPrice;
    newItem->tax = itTax;

    if (inInventory < MAX_INV)
    {
        inventory[inInventory] = newItem;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Inventory is full..." << endl;
    }
    delete newItem;
} while (i < bufferLength);
int upcInt = inventory[0].upc; // this is my error
}
```

However, Nick's solution seemed to have worked.

Comment: What is Item, newItem, inventory?

Comment: Please post a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question with the class definition.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the definition of your structure by missing a certain `#include`. But do post more code.

Comment: My includes are: iostream, string, and fstream

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Since @NickLamp's answer has solved your problem, see how to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inventory[inInventory] = newItem;
```

Leads me to believe that inventory is an array of pointers to `Item`s. If so, you need to use `inventory[0]->upc` to access an element's data members instead of `inventory[0].upc` because each element is a pointer to an `Item`.

Comment: This did it! Thank you!